# pdfbox error for using PDPageContentStream.drawLine

Tags: java, pdf, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I am using PDFBox for generating a pdf from one of my user inputted forms. For drawing a line I am using PDPageContentStream.drawLine and for text PDPageContentStream.drawString. The text works perfect but while using drawLine, when I try to print the pdf, I get the error as shown in the attached Image. My code looks like this

```
PDPage page = new PDPage();
release.addPage(page);
contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(release,page);
int margin = 40;
vertHeight -= thisFontHeight * fontSize * 1.05f + 5;

contentStream.drawLine(margin,vertHeight + margin - 5,                                     page.getMediaBox().getWidth() - margin, vertHeight + margin - 5)
```

Any help appreciated[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code sample doesn't show it, but I suspect you're mixing lines and text.  You must not draw lines between BT and ET.

1. begin Text
2. draw some text
3. end text
4. draw a line
5. begin text
6. draw some text
7. end text
8. draw some more lines
9. etc

If you drew a line between 1 and 3, for example, you'd get the above error (or one similar to it).

PS: If that's not it, we'll need a sample PDF to diagnose the issue.

Comment: Thanks Mark, that worked!! I was drawing lines between BT and ET, didn't find any resource which said this.

Comment: This one does:  http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/pdf/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf